# How do I get Visual Studio to run EsriRegasm.exe as administrator?

Tags: arcobjects, visual-studio

When run Visual Studio 10 as administrator and build a project with this in my csproj:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeClean">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(CommonProgramFiles)\ArcGIS\bin" 
      Command="esriRegasm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /p:Desktop /u " 
      Condition="Exists('$(TargetPath)')" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(CommonProgramFiles)\ArcGIS\bin" 
    Command="esriRegasm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /p:Desktop " />
  </Target>
```

It is able to do the clean (unregister) without any problems.  However it complains saying ...

> Registration failed.  Could not write to disk.

... when it does the AfterBuild.  (Notice I've removed the `/s` option on the command line.)

I have a bat file that can call EsriRegasm.exe without any problems when run as administrator.  However, when I run it as a non-admin I get the same error, which is expected.  Batch files run as admin results in spawned processes that are also run as admin.  Can Visual Studio do this too?

**Is there some option I can add to the csproj file to make it run EsriRegasm.exe as admin?**

I've already set my UAC to "never notify", as suggested by [kb 39158](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39158).  And set the file properties on EsriRegasm.exe to run as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting it in a [runas call](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)? That is, instead of

```
Command="esriRegasm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /p:Desktop " />
```

do

```
Command="runas.exe /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator esriRegasm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /p:Desktop " />
```

in the build step's command.

Alternately, you can edit the shortcut to `devenv.exe` in your start menu to [always run as administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx).